# SoveWhere is DB instance ID (DBInstanceIdentifier) to be found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds, boto3

**Where does one find the correct *DB instance ID,* to give as the 
`DBInstanceIdentifier` parameter to `boto3.client('rds').describe_db_log_files()`?**

The following database is shown on the RDS dashboard:

[image: sample RDS database]

But when I try to access it with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import boto3

def list_audit_files(db_id):
    response = client.describe_db_log_files(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    db_id = "eran-test-west-2-oracle"
    list_audit_files(db_id)
```

I get the following exception:

```
$ python3 so_db_instance.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_db_instance.py", line 14, in <module>
    list_audit_files(db_id)
  File "so_db_instance.py", line 8, in list_audit_files
    DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 601, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault: An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the DescribeDBLogFiles operation: DBInstance eran-test-west-2-oracle not found.
```

Where should I find the correct database instance ID?

### Solution:

The problem stemmed from a discrepancy between *the region the DB ran on* (us-west-1) and the *default region* as defined in `~/.aws/config` (eu-west-1). 
Once the region in `~/.aws/config` was fixed, the problem disappeared.

Comment: You should pass client as well to the list_audit_files, then try and see if you are getting the same error. Make sure you are using correct access key and secret key.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Isha. However, note that the Python interpreter is not complaining on `unknown client`, which means `client` is in the scope of the function. In any case, the same exception is received even if `client` is explicitly passed to the function as a parameter. As for _access key and secret key_ - they are passed correctly, as I wouldn't be able to get past the `client = boto3.client('rds')` line if they weren't.

Comment: Use describe_db_instances (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances).